# How to restart iteration in R loop?

Tags: r, markov-chains

I made a loop to generate a Markov Chain. If the proposal does not satisfy a condition, I want to restart the iteration with a new proposal? Is there a way to do this? My current code is shown below for reference. Currently, it sets the current chain's value to the previous one. But I don't want that. I want it to just restart the "i". So if i=2, and the condition in line 4 is not satisfied, I then want it to stay at i=2 until it is satisfied. Thanks in advance.

```
ABC_MCMC<-function(n){
      for (i in 2:n){
        prop<-rnorm(1,mean=chain[i-1],sd=1)
        if (ABC(prop)==T & prop>=0){
          h_ratio<-(dgamma(prop,shape=prior_alpha,rate=prior_beta)/dgamma(chain[i-1],shape=prior_alpha,rate=prior_beta))*
                   (dnorm(x=chain[i-1],mean=prop,sd=1)/dnorm(x=prop,mean=chain[i-1],sd=1))
          u<-runif(1)
          if (min(1,h_ratio)>u) {chain[i]=prop} else {chain[i]=chain[i-1]}
        }
        else{chain[i]=chain[i-1]}
      }
      return(chain<<-chain)
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to make `ABC_MCMC` recursive? Is that what you mean by "just restart the iteration"?

Comment: I mean: If the condition in line 4 is not satisfied, then go back to line 3. In other words, if that condition is not satsified, we never leave the current iteration until it is.

Comment: For that, you'll need to change your `for` loop to a `while` loop that increments `i` only if conditions are met. Since this can rapidly evolve into an infinite loop, you may want to put in safeguards so that you do not stay on the same value of `i` for more than "so many" iterations before giving up.

Comment: You should revise your coding: `return(chain<<-chain)` is probably dangerous.

Comment: I can do everything here within a while statement? And that wouldn’t need a for loop at all?

Comment: I used return(chain<<-chain) since the loop wasn’t saving the chain variable tk the global environment. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To save the `chain` variable to the global environment, assign the function return value.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than of an answer but to keep the code formatting I'm posting as an answer.

Replace the code inside the `for` loop for the code below.

```
while(TRUE) {
  prop <- rnorm(1, mean = chain[i - 1L], sd = 1)
  if (ABC(prop) && prop >= 0) {
    h_ratio<-(dgamma(prop,shape=prior_alpha,rate=prior_beta)/dgamma(chain[i-1],shape=prior_alpha,rate=prior_beta))*
      (dnorm(x=chain[i-1],mean=prop,sd=1)/dnorm(x=prop,mean=chain[i-1],sd=1))
    u<-runif(1)
    if (min(1,h_ratio)>u) {chain[i]=prop} else {chain[i]=chain[i-1]}
    break
  } else {chain[i] <- chain[i-1]}
}
```

---

## Edit

The function below seems to be what is asked for.

```
ABC_MCMC <- function(n){
  for (i in 2:n){
    # loops until condition (ABC(prop) & prop >= 0) is met
    while(TRUE) {
      prop <- rnorm(1, mean = chain[i-1], sd = 1)
      if (ABC(prop) & prop >= 0) {
        h_ratio <- (dgamma(prop, shape = prior_alpha, rate = prior_beta)/dgamma(chain[i - 1L], shape = prior_alpha, rate = prior_beta)) *
          (dnorm(chain[i - 1L], prop, 1)/dnorm(prop, chain[i - 1L], 1))
        u <- runif(1)
        if (min(1, h_ratio) > u) {
          chain[i] <- prop
        } else {
          chain[i] <- chain[i - 1L]
        }
        break
      }
    }
  }
  # function return value
  chain
}
```

Comment: Hmmm…what does this ameliorate? Thanks.

Comment: @LifeisGood94 It will repeat the line `prop<-rnorm(.)` until the condition is met and only then break the `while` loop. But every time through the `while` loop it will update `chain`, like in the code you've posted.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure here, I put what you show within my for loop? Or does this replace it? It appears that it should go inside the for loop. However, I don't want the chain updated if the condition isn't met. I think you're saying that this will still update the chain each time?

Comment: @LifeisGood94 In your code the `else` clause updates `chain`. If you do not want this, remove the clause. Wait, I will edit the code with a complete function.

Comment: @LifeisGood94 Done, see the edit. Note that to use variables in the function not defined nor passed as arguments is not a good practice. `prior_alpha`, `prior_beta` and `chain` should be function arguments.

Comment: @If `ABC(prop)` returns a scalar then the conjunction `&&` is better than `&`.

Comment: @LifeisGood94 Edited to `if (ABC(prop) && prop >= 0)`.